# MySQL Conditional If Exist Update Else Insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how do to a conditional Update else Insert, however I am having issue with my query and cannot find the issue. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM analytics WHERE visit_date="09-10-2019") THEN
    UPDATE analytics
    SET slug = "000aaa", visit_date="09-10-2019", visits="1", continent="NA", country="Canada", state="Quebec", city="Montreal"
    WHERE visit_date="09-10-2019";
ELSE
    INSERT INTO analytics (slug, visit_date, visits, continent, country, state, city)
    VALUES ("000aaa","09-10-2019", "1", "NA", "Canada", "Quebec", "Montreal");
END IF;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM analytics WHERE visit_date = "09-10-2019") at line 1

Comment: Any error reported?

Comment: Yes, I added it to question for everyone to see.

Comment: INSERT INTO analytics (slug, visit_date, visits, continent, country, state, city) VALUES ("000aaa","09-10-2019", "1", "NA", "Canada", "Quebec", "Montreal")
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE slug="000aaa", visit_date="09-10-2019", visits = "1", continent = "NA", country = "Canada", state = "Quebec", city = "Montreal"

Comment: 'MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html